# How to add google tag manager in flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to use Google Tag Manager in flutter application. Is there any plugin or package which helps to write GTM code in flutter?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue a month ago.

I added the GTM dependencies as I would do with a normal android app.
It doesn't matter if it is a Flutter app, you will have an `app/android` folder in your project in which you can add `graddle` dependencies.

This is a screenshot of my `app/android` folder and the `.build.graddle` file with the gtm dependency added (and also other google analytics ones).

[image: Project screenshot]

I recommend to follow [this steps](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v5?hl=es) for android and [this](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/ios/v5?hl=es) for iOS.

Comment: how to use it for flutter web?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add Google Tag Manager in flutter web project just navigate to web folder in your project and open index.html file. Then copy any paste the required code snippets from Google Tag Manager web container and paste them accordingly that index.html file. Follow this [link](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/web) to get read the full documentation of adding Google Tag Manger to web project.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no official flutter plugin provided by Google. Therefore, you need to directly apply the android, ios GTM plugin to the android, ios of your flutter app.
Relevant details are as follows:

- [ios documentation](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/ios/v5)
- [android documentation](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/android/v5)
- [tutorial](https://akhileshgahlot.medium.com/adding-tag-manager-to-flutter-app-ce528ec7852)

If you don't want to implement your own platform-specific implementations of your app, there is unofficial [gtm plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/gtm) for mobile